# I can not install openGLUT on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: opengl

I am trying to install openGLUT. I have downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openglut/files/development/OpenGLUT-0.6.3/ .

When I 'make' the configuration 'Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am' error is being shown. Have anyone able to install openglut? pls let me know.

Comment: Please specify exact file-name you downloaded.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use FreeGLUT instead? It can be installed via apt.

Comment: openglut-0.6.3.tar.gz from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openglut/files/development/OpenGLUT-0.6.3/

Comment: Looks like OpenGLUT is obsolete, those files have been updated in 2004. Try using FreeGLUT instead.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGLUT is obsolete and last updated in 2004. It's unlikely that it'll work on modern systems. Install FreeGLUT instead:

```
sudo apt install freeglut3-dev
```